# Crispy edges with topojson?

Tags: d3.js, maps, topojson

Mike Bostock shared a range of world wide topojson files.

As I wanted more data and higher quality, I now generate my own high quality topojson files from Natural Earth. To make it simple, my makefile / command is such:

```
admin_0: crop
    ../node_modules/topojson/bin/topojson \
        --id-property name \
        -p name=name \
        -q 1e4 \
        --filter=small \
        -o admin_0.topo.json \
        -- admin_0=./natural_earth_vector/10m_cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp
```

But my **3MB** [.topojson](https://rugger-demast.codio.io/output/world-1e3/administrative.topo.json) is crispy, nasty, graphically messy. Take a look at the coastline, you will see the most annoying thing : lines looking like "stairs" : horizontal, vertical, horizontal, vertical,...

[image]

On his side, M. Bostock's **90kb** [.topojson](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=7436f769930effc1a0211d4c3d67450a) does surprisingly fine in term of elegance. Not perfect, but nice, and he does have diagonals (!) and various angles used by his lines.

[image]

I tried reducing the quantization to `-q 1e3`, but it keeps crispy, and it's even more ugly: the stair's steps are even bigger.

From the [command line API](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference), I noticed and read as much as I could on :

- -q, --quantization, --no-quantization maximum number of differentiable points along either dimension
- -s, --simplify precision threshold for Visvalingam simplification
- --simplify-proportion proportion of points to retain for Visvalingam simplification
- --width scale and translate to fit a viewport of the specified width
- --height scale and translate to fit a viewport of the specified height

which may all help me. I made some test to mainly learn that [balancing simplification is tricky](http://une-terre.blogspot.fr/2013/08/d3js-balancing-gis-raster-precision.html). I would like to ask for experienced users how then handle and balance their topojson simplification.

What approach do you take yourself ? and so...
**What topojson parameters should I use to make my topojson nicer ?** (no crispy stairs-steps edge, correct loyalty the the shape)

Comment: you probably want to reduce the quantization parameter... try 1e8 and see if it helps, obviously, the more detail you have, the larger your TopoJSON file.

Comment: 1e8 will increase quantization and result into a super huge file.

Comment: Don't know a ton about this, but aren't you looking for the -s or --simplify-proportion parameters? Up your quantization factor and then use --simplify-proportion to bring down the file-size to whatever you want while maintaining perceptible detail. Fairly well discussed at https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference#simplification

Comment: Thanks Ethan. This is indeed close to what I currently plan to do. I am not sure that increasing `-q` then doing massive `-s` or  `--simplify-proportion` is good since simplification algorithms add distortions. Needing a final 1200px map, I'am currently going for quantification just above my need together with small simplification, something such `-q 1e4 -s <something small>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### -q VS -s

More details on **[Topojson: quantization VS simplification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900022/)** .

> The total size of your geometry is controlled by two factors: **the
> number of digits (the precision) of each coordinate** and **the number
> of points**.

The quantization `-q` reduce the number of digits for each coordinate. Initially, geopoints have very high precision such

```
…,[-90.07231180399987,29.501753271000098],[-90.06635619599979,29.499494248000133],…
```

Quantization **`-q 1e4`** where **1e4**=10000 creates a 10,000×10,000 grid with integer values between 0 and 9999 such `[-6700,1030]`. Characters by coordinate is reduced from ~40 to **12**, a ~75% reduction, with a maximum of **4** digits by value. Secondly, quatization makes geopoints which where distinct in the input shapefile to now share the same coordinates, such `[24,62],[24,62],[24,62]…`. These duplicates are merged. The end result are shapes defined by points on the grids. **If you ONLY use the quantization your shapes will be made of vertical + horizontal lines from grid-point to grid-point.**

In contrast, **simplification removes information by removing points**. The Visvalingam method used by the TopoJSON removes the least-noticeable points, the principle is wittily illustrated in [Line Simplification article](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/). To have many fine triangles to delicately removes, first use a higher quantization, then a simplification :

```
 #world
 topojson -q 1e6 -s 7e-5 -o world-110m.json -- NaturalEarth-110m.shp
```

It's the simplification which by removing some corner points create diagonals lines in topojson-based shapes.

#### -s

Asked on google group, M. Bostock [proposed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/a6VdcMv0VmU/X-a3xYrUUc0J) some smart tips.

> 4. For the USA, use `-s 7e-7`. "e" stands for exponent, measured in steradians for spherical coordinates. `7e-8` is ten times smaller, which is a lot more detail! 7e-5 is one hundred times less details.
>
> Lately, I’ve started pre-projecting the TopoJSON. This allows you to specify an intuitive simplification threshold in screen pixels (`--cartesian --width 960 -s 1` for one square pixel, e.g.) and makes rendering very fast on the client since the TopoJSON is already projected.

#### Demos

Two [live use](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6320825) and an other are such :

```
# projected (giving node extra memory since input shapefile is big)
us-albers.json: County_2010Census_DP1.shp
    node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/.bin/topojson \
        -q 1e5 \
        -s 1 \
        --projection 'd3.geo.albersUsa()' \
        --id-property=GEOID10 \
        -p name=NAMELSAD10,pop=+DP0010001 \
        -o $@ \
        -- counties=County_2010Census_DP1.shp

# non-projected (not used by this example, but included for reference)
  topojson --max_old_space_size=8192 \
     -q 1e6 \
     -s 7e-5 \
     -o world-110m.json \
     -- NaturalEarth-110m.shp
#USA
  topojson \
    -q 1e5 \
    -s 7e-7 \
    --id-property=GEOID10 \
    -p name=NAMELSAD10,pop=+DP0010001 \
    -o $@ \
    -- counties=County_2010Census_DP1.shp
```

With unprojected, as your mapped area's dimensions get 10 times smaller (i.e. Nevada), the `7e-7` should move to smaller values such `7e-8`.

#### Cartesian

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/